# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python, linux

System Info: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-88-generic x86_64)

Python is telling me that a module install installed that is:

```
trever@server:~/$ sudo pip3 install --target=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages Pillow
WARNING: The directory '/home/trever/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting Pillow
  Downloading Pillow-7.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 6.8 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-7.0.0
trever@server:~/$ python StartDatascraper.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StartDatascraper.py", line 1, in <module>
    import modules.only as onlyfans
  File "/home/trever/Only/modules/only.py", line 2, in <module>
    from modules.helpers import get_directory, json_request, reformat, format_directory, format_media_set, export_archive, format_image
  File "/home/trever/Only/modules/helpers.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
trever@server:~/OnlyFans$ cd /usr/local/lib/python3.8
trever@server:/usr/local/lib/python3.8$ ls
dist-packages  site-packages
trever@server:/usr/local/lib/python3.8$ cd site-packages/
trever@server:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages$ 
trever@server:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages$ ls
PIL  Pillow-7.0.0.dist-info
```

My python is set to Python 3.8.2

```
trever@server:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages$ python --version
Python 3.8.2
```

Edit 1:

```
trever@server:~$ python -c 'import sys;print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Edit 2:
I noticed that this is python3.6 instead of python3.8 though..

```
trever@server:~$ sudo pip3 install Pillow
[sudo] password for trever: 

WARNING: The directory '/home/trever/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (7.0.0)
```

Edit 3:

```
trever@server:~$ type python
python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)
```

Edit 4:

```
trever@server:~$ sudo /usr/bin/python -m pip install Pillow
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```

Comment: 'python StartDatascraper.py' are you sure that python is python3? On my debian is python2.7

Comment: I have mine set to Python 3.8.2. python --version outputs Python 3.8.2

Comment: sorry i didn't see that

Comment: Can  you run `python -c 'import sys;print(sys.path)'` ?

Comment: @Philippe I did, under edit 1

Comment: You can see sys.path does not contain `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` in which you installed PIL. Can you try installing without `--target=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

Comment: @Philippe how can I add that?

Comment: @Philippe I added that info under edit 2

Comment: You need to be careful with multiple versions installed. What does `type python` give you ?

Comment: @Philippe edit 3 :) I really don't need multiple versions installed but somehow its happened

Comment: Can you try `sudo /usr/bin/python -m pip install Pillow' ?

Comment: Edit 4, this maybe is the reason?

Comment: What I suggest is you tidy up python versions, install pip for 3.8, then install Pillow

Comment: Any directions on how to do all of that? I have no idea how to mess with python, the last time I did I broke it entirely.

Comment: This may be a starting point : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9711/what-is-the-proper-way-to-manage-multiple-python-versions